# Dynamically switch content in website based on user language selection

Tags: php, html, multilingual

I am designing a small, simple website that will need two languages. I want to keep things simple. I would like to use placeholders/variables in the code that will have user-visible text. Then, allow the user to the select the language of his choice (using a simple link), and make the entire site's text switch over to that language. I would prefer something similar to a language file, in which the values in the code are simply switched when the user selects his language. Below is a small example to illustrate what I am referring to.

```
<div class='title'>
  [$siteTitleGoesHere]
</div>
```

I hope that makes sense. I am familiar enough with php and javascript that I might be able to use them to do this, if given direction. Thanks for any help.

Comment: take a look at [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach..

Create a folder called `lang`

Inside this folder create your language files, lets say `en.php` and `fr.php`

These files contain an array called `$lang` that contains all the swappable text for your site.

for example in `en.php`

```
$lang['header'] = 'Welcome to my site!';
```

and in `fr.php`

```
$lang['header'] = 'Bonjour!'; // my french is awesome
```

You can then load the right file based on (for example) a session value

```
session_start();
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['lang'])) $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
require ("lang/{$_SESSION['lang']}.php");

echo $lang['header'];
```

If you wanted to change the language you could do something like this

in your php you will need to switch the session lang value to the new language

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    exit;
}
```

And you would use a link like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?lang=fr">French Language</a>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I go about switching the languages with a link?

Comment: Let me add an example of that to my answer

Comment: Can you tell me where the block of code that starts with `if (isset($_GET['lang']))`goes in the code? I'm confused there.

Comment: after the first bit :)

Comment: Oh my! It's beautiful. Works perfectly and exactly what I was looking for. I do have a lot yet to learn. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, keep at it champ :)