# Change language after POST

Tags: php

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548373/dynamically-switch-content-in-website-based-on-user-language-selection) tutorial to use multiple languages on my site, but i'm trying to switch language after POST, but actually the language switch happens when clicked on POST button twice.

This code is called out in the beginning of page.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'ENG';
    require "lang/ENG.php";
}
else {
    $language = (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : "ENG";
    switch($language) {
        case "EST":
            require "lang/EST.php";
            break;
        case "ENG":
            require "lang/ENG.php";
            break;
        default:
            require "lang/ENG.php";
    }
}
?>
```

This code is called out when form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['selectlang'])){
    $lang = $_POST['country'];
    //Change language??
}
```

If i click POST button twice, the language is switched, but not on the first try. What do i need to change?

Edit #2: Adding modified HTML now based on answers:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'ENG';
    require "lang/ENG.php";
}
else {
    $language = (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : "ENG";
    switch($language) {
        case "EST":
            require "lang/EST.php";
            break;
        case "ENG":
            require "lang/ENG.php";
            break;
        default:
            require "lang/ENG.php";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title><?php echo $lang['reklamatsioon_title'];?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/logo-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>


<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="reklamatsioon.php">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><?php echo $lang['link1'];?></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selector" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 control-label">Pick language</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9">
                        <span id="selector" class="input-group-btn">
                            <select id="country" name="riik" class="form-control">
                                <option <?php if($_POST['riik'] == "EST"){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> value="EST">Eesti</option>
                                <option <?php if($_POST['riik'] == "ENG"){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> value="ENG">English</option>
                                <option <?php if($_POST['riik'] == "FIN"){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> value="FIN">Suomi</option>
                                <option <?php if($_POST['riik'] == "SWE"){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> value="SWE">Rootsi</option>
                                <option <?php if($_POST['riik'] == "NOR"){ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> value="NOR">Norra</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="selectlang" type="submit">Choose language!</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['selectlang'])){
                $lang = $_POST['riik'];
                $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
                //Show code form and terms and conditions url!
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<form action='' method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                            echo "<label for='code' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>"."Code"."</label>";
                            echo "<div class='col-sm-6'>";
                                echo "<input type='number' id='code' name='code' placeholder='Code' class='form-control' autofocus>";
                                echo "<span class='help-block'></span>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                echo "<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>";
                                    echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' name='gobutton'>Continue to form</button>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                    echo "</form>";
                echo "</div>";
            }

            if(isset($_POST["gobutton"])){
                $codeVal = $_POST['code'];
                $brokenCode = false;
                if(strlen($codeVal) < 9){
                    $codeQuery = mysql_query("SELECT clientNumber FROM client WHERE clientNumber = '$codeVal'",$connection) or die(mysql_error());
                    if (mysql_num_rows($codeQuery) == 1){
                        header('location: ankeet.php?code='.$codeVal);
                    }
                    else {
                        $brokenCode = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $brokenCode = true;
                }
                if ($brokenCode){
                    echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "<form action='' method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>";
                            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                echo "<label for='code' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>"."Code"."</label>";
                                echo "<div class='col-sm-6'>";
                                    echo "<input type='number' id='code' name='code' placeholder='Code' class='form-control' autofocus value='".$codeVal."'>";
                                    echo "<span class='help-block'></span>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>Such code does not exist!</div>";
                                echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                    echo "<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>";
                                        echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' name='gobutton'>Continue to form</button>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                        echo "</form>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }

            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems like that you have some problem in your html part. show us. also if you have any jquery code attached with html then add that too in your question.

Comment: Added full HTML @AlivetoDie

Comment: `require ("lang/{$_SESSION['lang']}.php");` You switch the language only if the `isset($_SESSION['lang'])` exists. And init this value after the first "click" on the submit button, then on the second click this code works. Just try this code on the top of the page : `$_SESSION['lang'] = $_SESSION['lang'] ?:  'ENG'; require ("lang/{$_SESSION['lang']}.php");` instead of the `if ... else`

Comment: @Banana  i din't see `session_start();` in any of your code.how does this is working then?

Comment: Session is started in connection.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need:

```
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['country'];    
}
```

So the language can be switched.

Then you need to load your settings.

```
$language = (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : "ENG";
switch($language) {
    case "DE":
        require "lang/de.php";
        break;
    case "ENG":
    default:
        require "lang/eng.php";
}
```

That way nothing, that you dont want can happen

There are several other things you could optimize but for now that should solve your problem.

You should **NEVER** require or include a file based on a variable that can be set by the website user!

Edit:

I have seen your posted code now: It can not work because you first include your file and switch the session value later on. At that time the file has already been loaded. You need to do things in the correct order, just think of it like that:

1) initialize request

2) make configurations

3) output html code

**Edit again:**

There are so many bad practices in your code, that i actually dont know where to start.

1) Dont include user input unfiltered in SQL queries, that way you can be attacked by anyone with minimal knowledge. And people will try - believe me. You have to escape values, that are used in sql queries. It would be much better to use parameter binding, please google "php mysql pdo parameter binding"

2) When rendering your options, you should consider using a loop to avoid repeating yourself, please google "DRY dont repeat yourself"

3) you can not send a http header after you printed output already. That does not work due to the nature of the http protocol. First the headers are sent to the browser, followed by the content, basically it looks like:

```
HeaderLineOne: HeaderValue
HeaderLineTwo: HeaderValue

Content
```

3) You should really handle the request first and output your code later on. So put your php logic on top of the file (handle input, configure etc) and output your response at the end. That way you can react properly and dont mix up your view with your logic. Basically like:

```
<?php

// bootstrap application
require_once "connection.php";
require_once "other_include.php";

// configure
$language = "ENG";
if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $language = $_SESSION['language'];    
}

// allow user override for language
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $language = $_POST['country'];
    // make change persistent
    $_SESSION['language'] = $language;
}

// include translation labels
switch($language) {
    case "DE":
        require "lang/de.php";
        break;
    case "ENG":
    default:
        require "lang/eng.php";
}

// handle user request
if (isset($_POST['someValue'])) {
    // handle user input, make database calls etc
    // this is where your logic goes
}

// finally render response
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?= $lang['title'] ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?= $lang['title'] ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree, thanks for pointing that one out. However your code still did not fix the issue i'm having.

Comment: Please see my update. If you do it in the correct order it will work.

Comment: But i do have to display some language before user POST's the request thus i'd need to load the file first, atleast the default one.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on how to make my application more secure. As i've never had any actual tutorial on that and things i'm doing are self taught it's good to hear from professional perspective. I'll make changes and let you know.